# Why is SPContext.Current.Listitem Null? *Edited for clarity*

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

This is the code that's in a custom webpart **intended to be added to a document set**

I can't test it against a doc set because I can only get "SP foundation" loaded on my dev laptop, and so Doc Sets are not available.   Instead, I have created a document library, added a folder, and put 2 docs in the folder. I'm trying to execute this from within the folder against the docs therein.

I added the button that fires this code to the library page.
Here is the code that fires when the button is pressed:

```
   void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
**SPFolder folder = SPContext.Current.ListItem.Folder; **
char[] splitter = { '/' }; 
string[] folderName = folder.Name.Split(splitter); 
string filePrefix = @"Stock Analysis Demo/" + folderName[0] + "/" + folderName[0]; 

SPFile template = folder.Files[filePrefix + " - Template.docx"]; 
SPFile file; 
byte[] byteArray = template.OpenBinary(); 
  using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream()) 
{ 
  mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length); 

  using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true)) 
  { 
     MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart; 

     foreach (Word.SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document .Descendants<Word.SdtElement>    ().ToList()) 
     { 
        Word.SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<Word.SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault(); 
        if (alias != null) 
        { 
           string sdtTitle = alias.Val.Value; 

            if (sdtTitle == "Word:Document") 
           { 
              file = folder.Files[filePrefix + " - " + sdt.InnerText + ".docx"]; 
              AddAltChunk(mainPart, sdt, file);
```

I get an unhandledexception on SPContext.Current.ListItem is null.  **First line at the double-asterisk**

I have debugged and can get some of the SPContext methods to render info, its just that no "Listitem" is current.

I suspect, account a comment, that selecting a "document set" **makes the document set the current item**, and if so, the absence of a selected doc set prior to calling this code is why the current item is null.

...and furthermore, folders do not share the same properties as doc sets, so merely "opening" a folder does not make for a "current item"

Is this correct?

So how the heck do I test my custom webpart code against a doc set if I can't connect remotely to the actual site, and I can't get doc sets on my dev lap top?

OR........

Selecting a Doc Set does not set a current item.   So what would be a better way to loop thru the documents within this folder?

Comment: What do you mean you "have selected an item prior to pushing the button"?  What kind of page is this where you have your button?

Comment: I'm in a sharepoint "Shared Documents" library.  In the library I have a folder, in the folder I have 2 word documents. I've added a webpart w/ a  button that is attempting to run this code (again, the end-game is to loop thru all docs at this folder level & merge them), and prior to pushing the button I've ensured that one of the docs in this folder is selected.  To me, this means that there "is a current item".

Comment: incidentally, here is the url from within the folder that has 2 documents....is there some piece of this that I need?    http://ac4s-porlidesn1/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FShared%20Documents%2FBObs%20Folder&FolderCTID=0x0120005D7C7069F377F746B84A7EFD4DC33DCD&View={F3637EDF-17A5-4C5A-94E1-C677D261F609}&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EDocument&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence

Comment: I don't think checking a box in the UI really gives you a current item in this context. You could easily have selected multiple files, too, and then what would be the current item?

Comment: Well, OK.  I see your point.  In any case I can't seem to get the SPContext.Current.ListItem to NOT be null....any tips?

Comment: It will never NOT be null here from the list view page. It will only be available in a context where there is ONE list item... list item details page, for example. You may need to do more on the front end with your webpart to determine which things are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Farmer, you need some credit here....(or all of it)

Here's the deal:
A "Document Set" is an "item".
A Folder is not.

I had to use a 3rd party Virtual Machine to create the (non Foundation) sharepoint site and then the Visual Studio dev environment "on teh same server" so I could debug against a doc set.  Voila'- the listitem of a selected doc set made the context "see" a singlular listitem.